# Parametrize Jenkins Pipeline for different jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to use the same pipeline from scm, and build them in few jobs with different test tags to run(passed as simple String parameter)

I found that i can do this with:

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'param', defaultValue: 'Hello', description: 'How should I greet the world?')
}
```

I thought that i can change default value for each job there:
[Parametrize build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtWAS.png)

But it is overriden by code from pipeline everytime.

Is there a way to pass this parameter( or maybe pass parameter directly in job in different way)?
Or i have to create diferent pipeline files for each value of this parameter?

Thanks
Kamil

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to remove

```
parameters {
  string(name: 'param', defaultValue: 'Hello', description: 'How should I greet the world?')
}
```

from the pipeline script and to use **This project is parameterized** when creating pipeline jobs instead. This way the pipeline script is same for all jobs, but your jobs can have different parameters.

Comment: I tried this, but when parameter is not included inside pipeline then this one created inside job is deleted after first run

Comment: How do you mean deleted? Have you created the jobs manually?

Comment: It seems like list od parameters are taken from pipeline and those created via gui are reseted

Comment: If `parameters` directive is used inside of pipeline script, after first build, the defined parameters will appear in the job configuration GUI. If you change the parameters in the GUI and build pipeline again, it will take those changed parameters onyl for that build. It means, when the build is finished, the parameters will be reseted to the values defined in the script. Remove `parameters` directive and configure parameters manually when creating jobs.

Comment: i did as you said, first removed parameters from pipeline but when i add parameter in GUI it is only included in first run, then it disapears

Comment: It is strange. Have you provided **Default Value** for the parameter? Do you create the jobs manually?